# GetComponent<> в юнити

Tags: unity3d

Для чего нужен GetComponent в юнити? Без него же тоже самое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: " Без него же тоже самое."  --- есть пример?

Answer (score 1):

GetComponent()<> нужен для того, чтобы брать "компонент" у объекта. Это бывает полезно, когда используешь OverlapCircle(). Ты можешь обратится непосредственно к скрипту объекта, который засечет оверлап, и к переменным в них не используя instance и другие модели.

Comment: Увы, но нет... GetComponent придуман не для работы с OverlapCircle... По крайней мере ***очень далеко*** не только с ней... Остальное корректно

Answer (score 0):

`GetComponent` - это [обобщенная](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php) функция UnityEngine, которая позволяет получить компонент объекта.

Общий синтаксис этой функции таков:

`gameObject.GetComponent<название_компонента>()`;
или таков:
`gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(название_компонента));`

Например:

```
private GameObject Player; // Игровой объект персонажа
private BoxCollider PlayerCollider; // Коллайдер игрока

private void Start () {
    PlayerCollider = Player.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
}
```

`GetComponent` возвращает лишь один компонент, поэтому если на объекте висит несколько одинаковых компонентов может потребоваться [`GetComponents()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html)